# Struts2 Export JSP to Excel

Tags: jsp, struts2

In the .jsp file I iterate the userList and the header list . The id attribute of the  tag holds an instance of the data present in the list. this id is used in the java scriptlets to implement the application logic.

```
    <logic:iterate id="a" name="ExcelForm" property="userList">
                <tr>
                <logic:iterate id="b" name="ExcelForm" property="header">

                    <td>
                        String a = (data.get(header) instanceof String)? ((String) data.get(header)) : (((String[])data.get(header)).length > 1000 ? ((String[])data.get(header))[1000] : "");

                            .... 

 %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </logic:iterate>
```

Is necessary to convert this to Struts2  but I don't know how can I use the OGNL variable in the scriptlets.

```
<s:iterator var="a" value="%{userList}">
                <tr>
                <s:iterator var="b" value="%{header}">

                    <td>
                        String a = (data.get(header) instanceof String)? ((String) data.get(header)) : (((String[])data.get(header)).length > 1000 ? ((String[])data.get(header))[1000] : "");

                            .... 

 %>
                    </td>
                       </s:iterator>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`s:set` tag](http://struts.apache.org/docs/set.html) that creates a variable in a specified scope (action scope by default) and assign it a value as a result of OGNL expression evaluation.

```jsp
<s:set var="a" value='%{(data.get(header) instanceof String)? ((String) data.get(header)) : (((String[])data.get(header)).length > 1000 ? ((String[])data.get(header))[1000] : "")}'/>
```